# How to insert small bits of dynamic content into a file template?

Tags: php, file, templates

I have a situation in PHP where I need to reuse a `.md` file template consisting of markdown, and replace various bits of the template with dyamic data.

For example, given an array of `$dynamicData` like so:

```
array(
    'title' => 'foo'
    'summary' => 'summary'
    'sections' => array(
        [0] => 'long section of content',
        [1] => 'long section of content'
     ),
    'somethingUnique' => '1st April 2016'
)
```

I need to insert it into a .md template with the following psuedo structure:

```
# <<<TITLE HERE>>>

<<<SUMMARY>>>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet you get the idea. 

* Static
* list
* of
* things

foreach ($dynamicData['sections'] as $section) {
    <<< SECTION >>>
}

Static footer content.
```

How can I accomplish this? I don't want to have to build a string literal. **Additionally, I subsequently need to be able to read the resultant file out into a string and send it off to a third party.**

Are there any libraries available that make this task of dynamic content insertion into a arbitrary template easier?

Comment: i would set it up so that PHP processes the .md files for the directory that contains the .md templates, then put PHP in the .md files of that directory.

Comment: which template system are you using?

Comment: @JulioSoares blade (Laravel) at the moment